# Selecting a Different ROC Set Point in Caret

Tags: r, r-caret, roc

Is it possible to select a different ROC set point in the Caret Train function instead of using metric = ROC (which I believe maximizes the AUC).

For example:

```
random.forest.orig <- train(pass ~ x+y, 
                 data = meter.train,
                 method = "rf",
                 tuneGrid = tune.grid,
                 metric = "ROC",
                 trControl = train.control)
```

Specifically I have a two class problem (fail or pass) and I want to maximize the fail predictions while still maintaining a fail accuracy (or negative prediction value) of >80%. ie for every 10 fails I predict at least 8 of them are correct.

Comment: So you want to maximize classification accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the `caret::trainControl()` object to use AUC, instead of accuracy, to tune the parameters of your models. Please check the [caret documentation](https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#control) for details. (The built-in function, twoClassSummary, will compute the sensitivity, specificity and area under the ROC curve).

**Note: In order to compute class probabilities, the `pass` feature must be Factor**

Here under is an example of using 5-fold CV:

```
fitControl <- caret::trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 5,
  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
  classProbs = TRUE,
  verboseIter = TRUE
)
```

So your code will be adjusted a bit:

```
random.forest.orig <- train(pass ~ x+y, 
             data = meter.train,
             method = "rf",
             tuneGrid = tune.grid,
             metric = "ROC",
             trControl = fitControl)

# Print model to console to examine the output
random.forest.orig
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking to select a different point along the ROC curve (not maximizing the AUC). Specifically I am looking to maintain the negative prediction value at 80%, while still maximizing the number of predicted fails.

Comment: Are you referring to the best trade-off point on the ROC curve? i.e. Occam's razor

Comment: maybe you could take a look at this doc: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-77/topics/train